# C++ Memory access in Xcode behaves differently than eclipse

Tags: c++, ios

while writing native c++ code and i see same programme works fine in xcode(iOS), though crashes in eclipse(android). I could find the problem code and that was due a bad memory access. I wonder why xcode(iOS) didn't hit the same bad access hence crash.

Actually i created a class say "class_A" which inherits other class say class_B. Later in the code i created the same class instance pointer and assigned the return object of function foo() (belongs to class_B) which returns the object of type super class i.e class_B.

code snippet ...

```
class class_A : public class_B
{
public:

};

class_A *tempPart = (class_A *)class_A::foo("abc.png"); 

if(tempPart)
                {


                    -------------------
                   --------------------

 }
```

Now, while accessing _tempPart the programme crashes for android (eclipse), however xcode(iOS) always works fine. I could figure out that as fn foo() returns the object of type class_B hence i was assigning a super class(smaller size object) class_B's object to inherited class (a bigger size object) Class_A's object hence it was causing a bad memory access.

But i couldn't figure out why the same issue is not seen on xcode(iOS).
i am new to xcode and c++, so please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined behavior is undefined.

Doing things like accessing invalid memory results in undefined behavior in C++. The result may often be a crash, but C++ doesn't guarantee such things. Instead the program may simply behave oddly, or even exactly as you intended with no indication of an error. Different implementations may do different things.

Here's some info that may help explain why C++ has undefined behavior (as opposed to languages like Java which work very hard to rule out undefined behavior).

*What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior*

- [Part 1](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)
- [Part 2](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html)
- [Part 3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)

---

It's not entirely clear from your description what's really going wrong. You say something about assigning a bigger object to a smaller object causing bad memory access, however that's not the way assignment in C++ works, and the example code is using pointers anyway. The following code is completely legal and well defined, for example:

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {
  int i;
  void foo() { i = 100; }
};

B b = D(); // works fine, does not overwrite anything outside b. Slicing occurs.

B *bar() {
  return new D;
}

D *d = (D*)bar(); // works fine because the dynamic type matches.
```

Where a problem occurs is:

```
B *baz() { return new B; }

D *d = (D*)baz(); // not okay, undefined behavior. Anything can happen now, later, or even before this point.
d->foo(); // might crash, might not.
```

So, assuming this is what your program is doing, the same error in Java is well defined to cause an exception. In Objective-C the message passing machinery will try to find an implementation for the selector at runtime and if it does not find anything then an 'unrecognized selector' exception occurs.

Comment: Hey..thanks for a prompt reply. I had thought about undefined behavior , but what i found very weird that it always works fine over xcode(iOS) though crashes on eclipse(andorid). Hence i am wondering if there is really something special about either xcode or eclipse the way memory is being handled. Please advise.

Comment: That's the way undefined behavior is; sometimes a program with undefined behavior will 'always work fine.'

Comment: one more thing, what would be the result if same mistake happens in obj c or java ? Do they have some defined outcome for this ? Reason i am asking above code comes through porting obj c to c++, so just wondering if having this kind of assignment works for obj c but not for c++ or c ? Please confirm..

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation through code snippet. I am hitting the same problem code. However still not clear about abt obj c behavior..if we take same problem code, will that work for obj c, please explain.

Comment: An unrecognized selector is thrown by this example Obj-C code: http://pastebin.com/z5p4rqD8

Answer (score 0):

As @Bames53 has answered, this is undefined behavior. A quick fix would be to make `class_B::foo` a template function and rewrite it as follows

```
template <class ReturnClassType>
ReturnClassType *foo(std::string str){
```

You would then call it as

```
class_A::foo<class_A>("abc.png");
```

If you use public/protected functions to init the returned object, this should work.

Comment: Thanks Karthik. But it just wonder me that one platform crashes always and other doesn't.

Comment: @user1908860 Undefined behavior is typically implementation dependant, so the behaviour might change between platforms, between compilers on the same platform, or even between versions of the same compiler

Comment: one more thing, what would be the result if same mistake happens in obj c or java ? Do they have some defined outcome for this ? Reason i am asking above code comes through porting obj c to c++, so just wondering if having this kind of assignment works for obj c but not for c++ or c ? Please confirm..

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely upcast B to A.  B doesn't have a _useShader member.   You can only do vice versa:  B* = A*, but not A* = B*.  You may want to create a separate factory method for A objects.

Comment: I know this..but my question is that how this always works fine over xcode (iOS) but crashed on eclipse (Android)..

Comment: It is possible that it's only a coincidence that you haven't seen errors on the iOS side.  You may run into a different crash or see strange behavior in the future where this turns out to be the culprit.

Comment: one more thing, what would be the result if same mistake happens in obj c or java ? Do they have some defined outcome for this ? Reason i am asking above code comes through porting obj c to c++, so just wondering if having this kind of assignment works for obj c but not for c++ or c ? Please confirm..

Comment: I would think ObjC would have the same problem.  Java would not let you compile.